# Rails 5: redirect to random page after successful payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently adding a client dashboard, where clients can choose betwenn different offers.

Now, I would like to add unique redirect for each successful payment.

I was thinking of something similar like this:

1. Client makes payment
2. Client is redirect to a random url
3. Client submits a form

My reservations controller

```
def create
  service = Service.find(params[:service_id])

if current_user.admin?
  flash[:alert] = "Du kannst nicht dein eigenes Angebot kaufen"
elsif current_user.stripe_id.blank?
  flash[:alert] = "Füge eine Zahlungsmehtode hinzu"
  return redirect_to payment_method_path
else
  @reservation = current_user.reservations.build(reservation_params)
  @reservation.service = service
  @reservation.price = service.price

  if @reservation.Bearbeitung!
    flash[:notice] = "Ihre Anfrage wurde erfolgreich versendet"
    ReservationMailer.confirm_email_to_guest(@reservation.user, service).deliver
    confirm_sms(service, @reservation)
  else
    charge(service, @reservation)
  end

end
 redirect_to 'RANDOM URL'
end
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What is `random url`? Is it some app url with token?

Comment: No it's just a placeholder, I'm still not sure how I would achieve this, so I'm open for suggestions from the community

Comment: redirect_to internal url or to other domain?

Comment: It should be an internal url

Comment: you can redirect_to reservation show path on success by `redirect_to reservations_path(@reservation)`

Comment: @UdAY yes that's it! I forgot why I didn't add `show` to my controller, now I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set predefined array of paths

like -

```
paths_array = [example_1_path(x), example_2_path(x,y), example_3_path(z)..]
random_path = paths_array.shuffle.first
redirect_to random_path

#redirect_to reservations_path(@reservation) # To redirect to show action.
```